# Edit Woocommerce checkout template

Tags: php, templates, woocommerce

thanks to all in advance,
I'm quite new to woo costume edits and was wondering how can I change the woo  checkout fields to look like in the picture (included).
I'v tried to look up at the form-billing.php & form-checkout.php, but didn't figure out where all the fields so I can manipulate the  output and edit in css all the rest.

regarding the issues a few more question:

1.can this be done with action/filters or need to be hand coded?

2.can I append an #id via functions.php to certain parts of woo commerce

sure you guys could help, cheers to all

[**Image:**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDOmu.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

There are actions and filters you can use to do loads of stuff with woocommerce checkout: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/

However a quick css fix for what you want is:

```html
#billing_address_1_field {
 width: 48%;
 float: left;
    clear: none;
}
#billing_address_2_field {
 width: 48%;
    float: right;
    clear: none;
 padding-top: 36px;
}
```

That worked for me.

Comment: niceee, working great man ,appreciate thank you. 
I'm just wondering where can I find all of the fields I want to practice on php coding.

Comment: When you are at the checkout, inspect the element in your browser to find the ID of that field - you can then edit any fields. With regards to editing the fields via PHP and practising, use the examples at https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/ and try modifying the outcome.

Comment: Thanks bro Il check it out , the issue is that some of the fields are not under the same col so I need to modify it to be on the same Col inside the same div and as far as I understand (most likely i'm wrong) you need to modify the html via php only

Comment: No worries, ye you need the actions and filters for that or you could try copying the woocommerce template files into your theme and implementing your changes that way...https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/